# Por que o partilhar do ngcordova não funciona?

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Tenho um app móvel e estou a usar o plugin do `ngcordova`, o `cordovaSocialSharing`. Mas quando fiz como a documentação, quando clico em partilhar não acontece nada.

**Controller**

```
.controller('ShareCtrl', function($ionicPlatform, $scope, $cordovaSocialSharing) {
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    var message = 'This is a demo message';
    var subject = 'This is a demo message';
    var link = 'http://somerandom.link/image.png'; // fake image

    $scope.nativeShare = function() {
        $cordovaSocialSharing
            .share(message, subject, link); // Share via native share sheet
    };

    //checkout http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/socialSharing/
    // for other sharing options
});
})
```

**Botão**

```
 <div ng-click="shareAnywhere()" ng-controller="ExampleController" style="text-align: center">
 <i style="font-size: xx-large" class="ion-android-share-alt"></i><br>
 Partilhar
 </div>
```

Comment: Você chegou a iniciar a variável app? Outra coisa, coloque o ng-controller antes do ng-click. Consegue partilhar esse fonte em algum lugar?

Comment: O ng-controller já coloquei ai em cima e a variável app esta inicializada

Comment: Chegou a colocar a tag ng-app no html?

Comment: Tem no index.html ng-app="starter"

Comment: O index.html é o mesmo que tem o teu html com controller?

Comment: Não o controller esta noutra pagina mas estou a usar routes

Comment: Tente colocar tudo na mesma página

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que ter em mente que os plugins do cordova não funcionarão no browser. Você precisa emular um dispositivo ou fazer o 'build' do app e instalar ele em seu device.

O seu button também deve ser modificado para chamar a função `nativeShare` que você mencionou no controller `ShareCtrl`.

```
<div ng-click="nativeShare()" ng-controller="ExampleController" style="text-align: center">
  <i style="font-size: xx-large" class="ion-android-share-alt"></i><br> Partilhar
</div>
```

Comment: Já modifiquei e testei com a app instalado no aparelho e nao funciona nao faz nada quando clico

Comment: Você configurou/habilitou o ng-cordova corretamente? Você precisa instalar o plugin, e incorpora-lo dentro das dependências do app.js

Comment: Sim tenho isso todo ate que estou a usar outros plugins do ngcodova e funionam so este e que nao